# Why are Viking LR results not sufficient evidence of life on Mars?

Tags: mars, nasa, life, astrobiology, viking

Gil Levin, one of the scientists involved with the 1976 Viking mission to Mars, has claimed and continues to claim that there is life on Mars, based off the positive results of the Labeled Release (LR) experiment.

This was the only one of the landers' four life-detecting instruments that returned positive results, but prior to the mission it was expected that because of the instruments' radically different approaches, actual Martian organisms might still only return positive results in one of them. Furthermore, there is no evidence (to my knowledge) that the LR instrument was faulty, nor that LR's strong positive results could be explained by any non-biological process. (Levin details his fairly comprehensive explanation and argument for life on Mars in [this paper](http://www.gillevin.com/Mars/Levin-Straat_Mars_Society_Paper_8-8-14.pdf)).

Despite these findings, scientific consensus still posits that no life on Mars has ever been detected, by LR or any other experiment. My question is simply: Why?

Can anyone point me to a *credible source, statement, or publication* that addresses LR's results and explains why they don't constitute sufficient evidence for life on Mars?

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. Viking did not provide that. You should ask the other question: why, with such poor and ambiguous evidence, would anyone believe there is life on Mars?

Comment: This kind of attitude is exactly what I'm talking about. Where is the rationale? Yes, there's the extraordinary claims/evidence argument, but in this case, the extraordinary evidence is that an instrument specifically designed to test for life in Mars performed multiple successful tests without error and produced positive results every time, with no plausible alternative explanations. At what point do we say, "We set out to test for this thing, and our test says we found it"?

Comment: What attitude? You mean scientific rigor? The experiment was NOT designed to find life, none so far is. It was designed to find released $^{14}CO_2$ gas and it did, albeit in a confusing and incoherent manner (your statement "produced positive results every time" is wrong, why would you lie on the internet), that is inconsistent with what we'd expect from life. The other experiments on the Vikings gave negative results. I don't see any strong evidence for life here. Also only parroting one guy that has a history of overselling his results is not a very credible approach to science.

Comment: You're right, I should've said "produced positive results every time, except in control scenarios where negative results were expected and further supported the hypothesis." Beyond that, your logic is circular and your evidence nonexistent. Welcome to StackExchange, please provide sources for the "confusing and incoherent" results you claim were produced. I started this question by stating that I couldn't find sources that reliably refuted "the one guy." If you have one, please share and post an answer. Otherwise, you're just parroting what YOU have been told. Where's the scientific rigor?

Comment: No, I was referring to the repeated experiment, which showed nothing. That's called inconclusive evidence in science. Welcome to science btw. I'll post an answer, but first I want to go through a few more of the non-biological papers which Levin in the link you've posted does not only not cite, but also just flatly refutes them without much further comment. Him supporting his views with a list of names agreeing with him, makes him look even more strange.

Comment: Short follow-up: The Yen+2000 paper https://science.sciencemag.org/content/289/5486/1909.full.pdf+html seems to explain the experiment+control well. It has been cited by a paper with Levin on it only once: http://koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO201213549741763.page which I haven't read yet. Is that the explanation which you've referred to as 'disproven' in your comment to @MSalters answer?

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I'd heard of it but hadn't seen Yen's paper myself. The "disproven" hypothesis was that of hydrogen peroxide rain on Mars, but Yen's theory of UV-activated superoxides holds merit. I didn't know Yen also accounted for LR's sub-rock and heated sample findings. However, Levin argues that Viking and Pathfinder both show that the Martian surface isn't "highly oxidized," citing Viking's Magnetic Properties Experiment (MPE) & Pathfinder's mineral oxidation analysis. Do you know what level of oxidation would be required to be consistent with LR, MPE, & Yen's theory?

Comment: No I don't know that. I would expect they'd have a follow up paper, diving deeper into the oxidation issue, but so far the citation tree hasn't shown much. How do they link the magnetic level and oxidation btw? I saw this in Levins article, but didn't really get the point. Do they assume a certain oxygen ratio in the magnetised crust?

Comment: My understanding was that oxidation tends to weaken a material's magnetic properties. Chemistry isn't my strong suit, though, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The Search for Life on Mars (Christopher P. Mckay, 1996) quotes

1. Klein, H. P.: 1978, Icarus 34, 666–674.
2. Klein, H. P.: 1979, Rev. Geophys. Space Phys. 17, 1655–1662.
3. Horowitz, N. H.: 1986, To Utopia and Back: The Search for Life in the Solar System, W.

Also by Mckay:

4 .McKay C. P. et al.  1998. The Mars Oxidant experiment (MOx) for Mars '96. Planet. Space Science 46:769–777.

In short, it's the common scientific problem. The Labeled Release Experiment is **not** evidence **against** life. The result outcomes are compatible with multiple mechanisms, including but not limited to microbial life.